# SWA conflict with Apple and Google Store agreements?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-play, itunes-store

I have a couple of apps in both Apple iTunes and Google Play. Managing the paid content subscriptions has been a pain, so it seemed like a great idea when Amazon introduced "Subscribe With Amazon" (see [SWA Integration Guide](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/swa-public-documents/integration-guides/SWA_SellerIntegrationGuide.pdf)). I could potentially get away with a single platform to manage all the subscriptions.

But won't this cut into Apple & Google profits? Why would they allow this? Couldn't find any information on this topic anywhere, has anyone using SWA run into this issue? Will Apple & Google allow the subscriptions to be managed via Amazon?

Only looking for business clarification, not API/technical help.

Answer (score 0):

But won't this cut into Apple & Google profits? Why would they allow this? Couldn't find any information on this topic anywhere, has anyone using SWA run into this issue? Will Apple & Google allow the subscriptions to be managed via Amazon?

-> **For Apple** refer 
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#subscriptions

With my understanding of section 3.1.1 bullet 1, **your app will be rejected for anything else used outside IAP**. Again it's at apple's approval team's discretion to reject or approve app.

"If you want to unlock features or functionality within your app, (by way of example: subscriptions, in-game currencies, game levels, access to premium content, or unlocking a full version), you must use in-app purchase. **Apps may not include buttons, external links, or other calls to action that direct customers to purchasing mechanisms other than IAP.**"

->**For google** - Refer https://play.google.com/about/monetization-ads/

Your **app will be rejected** if you use any other payment for in-app purchases

In-store purchases: Developers charging for apps and downloads from Google Play must use Google Play’s payment system.

**Payment from outside is allowed only in below case**

Developers offering products within another category of app downloaded on Google Play must use Google Play In-app Billing as the method of payment, except for the following cases:

**Payment is solely for physical products**

**Payment is for digital content that may be consumed outside of the app itself (e.g. songs that can be played on other music players).**